# Azure blob download is blocked

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am downloading a large Azure blob (6 GB) from a web application.
The blob is successfully downloaded to the web server after about 40 minutes, but the application is blocked in the WCF line of code that  downloads the blob, and then gives a timeout exception. I the file is smaller I don't have this problem.

Here is the code:

MVC controller:

```
        timeoutMinutes = 60;

        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(EndPoint);
        factory = new ChannelFactory<RemotingServiceLibrary.IRemotingService>(binding, address);
        factory.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, timeoutMinutes, timeoutSeconds);
        IRemotingService channel = factory.CreateChannel();

        channel.LoadBlob(containerName, blobName, sqlMachineBackupFile, connectionString);
```

WCF:

```
    public string LoadBlob(string blobContainer, string blobName, string DestinationFilePath, string connectionString)
    {
        try
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(blobContainer);
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

            int segmentSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

            blob.FetchAttributes();
            var blobLengthRemaining = blob.Properties.Length;
            long startPosition = 0;
            do
            {
                long blockSize = Math.Min(segmentSize, blobLengthRemaining);
                byte[] blobContents = new byte[blockSize];
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    blob.DownloadRangeToStream(ms, startPosition, blockSize);
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    ms.Read(blobContents, 0, blobContents.Length);
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(DestinationFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        fs.Position = startPosition;
                        fs.Write(blobContents, 0, blobContents.Length);
                    }
                }
                startPosition += blockSize;
                blobLengthRemaining -= blockSize;
            }
            while (blobLengthRemaining > 0);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
        return "OK";
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of downloading the blob first on your web server and then downloading it to the client, can you not use shared access signature and directly download the blob on the client?

Comment: I don't download it to the client, it's a database backup, I download it with WCF from Azure to the machine with Sql Server, and then do the restore. The restore succeeds because the file is correctly downloaded, but I would like to avoid the blocking of the function and then the timeout. No idea of how to do it.

Comment: Though I haven't tried it but one other possibility would be download asynchronously (`DownloadToStreamAsync`) and keep on monitoring the progress of download.

Comment: This asynk stuff does not work, the file is created in the destination folder but not downloaded, its size is 0. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yet another thing you could do is download chunks instead of whole 6 GB blob in one go. So your client will ask WCF service to download pages (say 4 MB page in each request). When the page is downloaded, it gets appended to the file. This way your requests will be of smaller duration and you won't face timeout issues.

Comment: Thank you Gaurav, I used the code that you kindly gave me in my other question in order to download chunks. Your code works perfectly, but I still have the problem that even if the blob is downloaded, the application is blocked on the line that launches the download. This only happens if this line is executed in the WCF method in an Azure virtual machine. If I run this line locally, the application is not blocked.

Comment: It would be hard to comment without looking at the entire code. Will it be possible for you to share the entire code (including WCF service and client code)?

Comment: I have modified my question, but I don't know if it will help you. The timeout is never reached, the download is ok but the LoadBlob function never returns. I wanted to debug this function in local, but in local there are no problems!

Comment: May be I was not clear earlier. Sorry about that. What I really meant was to break your WCF service into multiple calls. 1st call would be to fetch blob properties so that you can get the size of the blob and initiate the download process. In the subsequent WCF calls, you download the blob in parts and start saving them on the file.

Comment: Yes, but your advice was in order to solve a timeout problem. The problem is not a timeout, since the function is blocked and does not return anything, and the timeout occurs more than 10 minutes later. This is a very strange behavior and I need to test more, I'll keep you informed. Thank you.